# Paginate Laravel 5.2 with Jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

I know how to paginate in Laravel, I tried it according to its docs and its so easy.However, I am implementing a Jquery autocomplete on its one of its view, and pagination this time does not work. How would you achieve this?

jquery

```
  $("#city_autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: '/lead-users/autocomplete',
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#city_autocomplete").val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
```

Controller

```
 $leads = LeadUser::where('gender', 'LIKE', '%'.$gender.'%')
            ->orderBy('first_name', 'ASC')
            ->paginate(20);
```

View

```
<tbody>
            @foreach($leads as $count)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $count->getFullName() }}</td>
                <td>{{ $count->email }}</td>
                <td>{{ $count->city }}</td>
                <td>{{ $count->state }}</td>
                <td>{{ $count->getGender() }}</td>
                <td>{{ $count->yesOrNo() }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    {{ $counts->links() }}
```

Ok I update my Jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#city_autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: '/lead-users/autocomplete',
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#city_autocomplete").val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
        $(window).on('hashchange',function(){
            page = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
            getItems(page);
        });
        $(document).on('click','.pagination a', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
            // getItems(page);
            location.hash = page;
        });
        function getItems(page){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/lead-users/autocomplete?page=' + page
            }).done(function(data){
                $('#leads').html(data);
            });
        };
    });
</script>
```

This will only work for the pagination 2(1,2,3,4,5,6) the rest will not redirect.It does change the url in the browser but nothing happens on the view

```
city=Fremont#2
city=Fremont#3
city=Fremont#4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in your controller

```
  $leads = LeadUser::where('gender', 'LIKE', '%'.$gender.'%')
        ->orderBy('first_name', 'ASC')
        ->paginate(20);
  return $leads->appends(['gender' => $gender]);
```